# Spring, Hibernate with google app engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

Project Name: CarpoolDB, I have added the jar for this project in another application name Carpool.
While running the Carpool app I am getting following exception.

Project: Carpool.
Here i am getting exception as "carpoolService" not getting autowired while running as "Google Web application" but same runs under Tomcat and beans properly get injected.

```
@Controller
public class PlacesSearchController {

    @Autowired
    CarpoolService carpoolService=null;

    public CarpoolService getCarpoolService() {
        return carpoolService;
    }
    public void setCarpoolService(CarpoolService carpoolService) {
        this.carpoolService = carpoolService;
    }

}
```

carpool-application-context1.xml

Also I have applicationContext-security.xml, for spring security.

Project: CarpoolDB
All class are in package, com.company.carpooldb.db

```
    public interface CarpoolService {
        public boolean validateUser(User user);
    }

    @Service("carpoolService")
    public class CarpoolServiceImpl implements CarpoolService{

        @Autowired
        private CarpoolDao carpoolDao=null;

        public CarpoolDao getCarpoolDao() {
            return carpoolDao;
        }

        public void setCarpoolDao(CarpoolDao carpoolDao) {
            this.carpoolDao = carpoolDao;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean validateUser(User user) {
              return carpoolDao.validateUser(user);;
        }

    }


public interface CarpoolDao {
  public boolean validateUser(User user);
}

public class CarpoolDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements CarpoolDao{
    @Override
    public boolean validateUser(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

carpool-application-context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.onmobile" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:server.properties" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory" 

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
     <list>
            <value>com\company\carpooldb\hbm\User.hbm.xml</value>
     </list>   
     </property>
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"><!--Which dialect is used of hibernate according to type of underlying database-->
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property> 

</bean>


<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName"><beans:value>${cm.db.driverClassName}</beans:value></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="url"><beans:value>${cm.db.url}</beans:value></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="username"><beans:value>${cm.db.username}</beans:value></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="password"><beans:value>${cm.db.password}</beans:value></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="testOnBorrow"><beans:value>true</beans:value></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="testOnReturn"><beans:value>true</beans:value></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="validationQuery"><beans:value>select 1</beans:value></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

    <!--Hibernate's transaction manager used for handling database transactions/manipulating data happening-->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" >
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="carpoolDaoImpl" class="com.company.carpooldb.db.CarpoolDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

While running the application, I am getting exception as,

```
log4j:WARN Error during default initialization
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
.........

    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:162)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
11 Nov, 2012 5:14:18 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@5e55ab{/,D:\EclipseEuropa\CarpoolingGAE\war}
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'placesSearchController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolService com.onmobile.carpool.controller.PlacesSearchController.carpoolService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolDao com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolServiceImpl.carpoolDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
.........   
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolService com.onmobile.carpool.controller.PlacesSearchController.carpoolService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolDao com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolServiceImpl.carpoolDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolDao com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolServiceImpl.carpoolDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
....    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:780)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolDao com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolServiceImpl.carpoolDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
....    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
....    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
....    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 66 more
11 Nov, 2012 5:14:18 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'placesSearchController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolService com.onmobile.carpool.controller.PlacesSearchController.carpoolService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolDao com.onmobile.carpooldb.db.CarpoolServiceImpl.carpoolDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carpoolDaoImpl' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.id.AbstractUUIDGenerator.<clinit>(AbstractUUIDGenerator.java:22)
    ......at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
.....
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
.....   at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

Why I am getting as 
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class.

I am not writing anything on file

1. GAE doesn't support few API that I am aware of but my application already working for MySQL and I want to support both. I mean based on property set in my property file I want to use sometime MySQL and sometime want to work with GAE datastore.

I am using spring 3.

What I should do in this case?

Comment: This problem is not about Spring - it's about log4j trying to write a log to the file and doing that is prohibited by Google Apps. The same goes to DaoImpl: java.net.InetAddress is restricted by Google Apps.

Comment: @BorisTreukhov, I had log4j.xml file in my app but after going throw app documentation I came to know that such exception is due to logs writing to File, so i removed log4j.xml just to make sure that no logs is written. The code which I provide is complete, can you please point out the exact root cause of this problem...

Comment: When you see a bean creation exception you should read the Spring stack trace bottom up: it shows Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [carpool-application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.net.InetAddress is a restricted class.   So the problem is with the sessionFactory

Comment: @BorisTreukhov, I have written the same that I am aware of the exception which is coming for session factory. I have two question here, 1. what I should do to remove  "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class". 2. I have already built my application using MySQL and I want it to keep it scalable for Google App engine support as well, what to do in that case?

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/4210472/jdbc-driver-does-not-work-with-gwt

Answer (score 3):

As Boris notes, the issue appears to be with your session factory.  GAE doesn't support jdbc, and it looks like your sessionFactory is configured for mysql:

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect"><!--Which dialect is used of hibernate according to type of underlying database-->
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

If you're working with an existing codebase that depends on Hibernate, you could try configuring Hibernate to run backed by Cloud SQL: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_hibernate

As for the FileOutputStream issue, I believe one of the default appenders for log4j is a FileAppender, so simply not configuring log4j won't fix it - you'll need to explicitly configure it.  See if this page helps: http://blog.xam.de/2010/03/logging-in-google-appengine-for-java.html

Comment: The bad news is that is seems that google-app-engine simply doesn't support hibernate at all. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava

Comment: link that ends with "using_hibernate" is broken